# Post-Brexit: Is a UK visa needed for a UK citizen's non-EU spouse with EU Article 50 Residence Card to visit the UK together?

Tags: visas, uk, brexit

Post-Brexit, Is a UK visitor visa needed for a UK citizen's non-EU spouse with EU Article 50 Residence Card to visit the UK together? I am a Chinese citizen, living with my UK citizen spouse in Germany. We want to visit the UK together at some point. We both have resident cards issued under article 50.

Comment: At what date are you planning to travel? Before or after 30 June 2021? Not sure it really matters in your specific case, but a few things change at that time (including "Surinder Singh" family permits, but i'm not sure they apply here).

Comment: Useful link: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: I guess the [question in the sidebar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118328/is-a-uk-visa-needed-for-a-uk-citizens-non-eu-spouse-with-eu-family-member-resid?rq=1) which looks very similar is actually out of date now?

Comment: @jcaron maybe before 30 June, but yeah just for a short visit so Surinder Singh is not quite applicable